# Android - RecyclerView Obscured By BottomNavigationView

Tags: android

I created the default bottom navigation project.  In one of the fragments I added a `ListView`, that worked fine.  Then I changed that to a `RecyclerView`, it gets obscured by the `BottomNavigationView`.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the layout for the main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the layout for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DiaryFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the `RecyclerView` contains more rows than fit on the screen, then the last row appears partially behind the `BottomNavigationView`.  I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Edit - here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Edit #2: In the first layout, if I move the `BottomNavigationView` inside the `LinearLayout` (thanks @Juanje), and change its `android:layout_width` from `0dp` to `match_parent`, then the `RecyclerView` is no longer obscured by the `BottomNavigationView`, but now the `FloatingActionButton` is cast adrift:

[image]

I am tinkering with it, I would be grateful for any ideas.

Edit #3

Below is what I ended up with after following the accepted answer plus a couple other tweaks.  The necessary changes were:

1) In the first layout:

- Move the `BottomNavigationView` inside the `LinearLayout`
- In the `BottomNavigationView`, change `android:layout_width` from `"0dp"` to `"match_parent"`

2) In the second layout:

- In the `FloatingActionButton`, change `android:layout_marginBottom`
  from `"70dp"` to `"10dp"`

The first layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The second layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DiaryFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the `BottomNavigationView` inside the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: this fixes the layout problem - the bottom navigation no longer obscures the last item in the recyclerview - but now the bottom navigation is a blank white box, the navigation tabs are no longer visible.

Comment: i fixed the "blank" problem by going in to the BottomNavigationView and changing android:layout_width from "0dp" (which is the value created by the example project) to "match_parent".  now the FAB is no longer aligned to the bottom of the screen, but i think i'm getting closer...

Comment: You could use a `CoordinatorLayout` and use the anchor property.

Comment: i tried that and still found that the `FloatingActionButton` was too high.  then i noticed this in the `FloatingActionButton`:

`android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"`

that should be `10dp`.  in an earlier iteration i must have increased the value in order to raise the `FloatingActionButton` above the `BottomNavigationView`, which of course is not the right way to go about it.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set some constraints, otherwise your elements overlap. Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigation"> <!--Added here and one line above; changed height: 0dp height means match constraint-->

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any reason that the RecyclerView should be in a LinearLayout inside the ConstraintLayout? The LinearLayout seems potentially unnecessary.

Comment: @S.Miller sure, but that's the Fragment layout, and I'm talking about the Activity layout.

Comment: many thanks for getting back to me, but unfortunately adding these lines didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you edit a picture into your question? @user2022499

Answer (score 2):

The important attributes for `fragment` element is setting **`android:layout_height="0dp"`** to match the constrains layout and adding **`app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"`** to make the `fragment` be above the `BottomNavigationView`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with `SwipeRefreshLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/people_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`BottomNavigationView` is wrapped by `ConstraintLayout` and looks like:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
```